# How to Split a TF1 Saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was studying on the project StegaStamp and I was trying to deploy it on a server using TFServing. When calling the interface, I found that I seemed to have to pass in Image and Secret at the same time, and the model would also return the encoded image, residual, and decoding results. In fact, input and results are optional corresponding encode and decode operations during local training and use. I think this should affect the performance of the model. There is no need to perform decoding related operations in encode, so I tried to separate the model into two separate models.

```
# %%
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

# %%
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    metagraph_def = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.compat.v1.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                                         'D:/work/project/StegaStamp/model/pretrained_model/')
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
    all_vars = tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
    input_secret_name = metagraph_def.signature_def[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].inputs[
        'secret'].name
    input_secret = graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_secret_name)
    input_image_name = metagraph_def.signature_def[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].inputs[
        'image'].name
    input_image = graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_image_name)

    output_stegastamp_name = metagraph_def.signature_def[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].outputs[
        'stegastamp'].name
    output_stegastamp = graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_stegastamp_name)
    output_residual_name = metagraph_def.signature_def[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].outputs[
        'residual'].name
    output_residual = graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_residual_name)
    output_secret_name = metagraph_def.signature_def[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].outputs[
        'decoded'].name
    output_secret = graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_secret_name)

    sub_graph_encode = tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph(
        sess.graph_def, [input_image.op.name, input_secret.op.name, output_stegastamp.op.name, output_residual.op.name])
    sub_graph_decode = tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph(
        sess.graph_def, [input_image.op.name, output_secret.op.name])

    # 创建新的图和会话 导入原始模型的子图到新的图中
    new_graph = tf.Graph()
    with new_graph.as_default():
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(sub_graph_encode, name="")
    with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=new_graph) as new_sess:
        # 获取新图中的变量
        new_vars = tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)

        # 初始化新模型的变量
        init_new_vars = tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer(new_vars)
        new_sess.run(init_new_vars)
        # 加载原始模型的参数到新的变量中
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            # 加载原始模型的参数
            tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
                                                 "D:/work/project/StegaStamp/model/pretrained_model/")

            # 获取原始模型子图的参数
            original_vars = tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES,
                                                        scope="")  # 替换为原始模型子图的作用域

            # 将参数赋值给新的变量
            for var, original_var in zip(new_vars, original_vars):
                new_value = sess.run(original_var)
                var.load(new_value, new_sess)

    # 将新模型保存为 SavedModel
    builder = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(
        "D:\\work\\project\\StegaStamp\\saved_models\\encode_model")
    predict_signature_def = (
        tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={"image": tf.compat.v1.saved_model.build_tensor_info(input_image),
                    "secret": tf.compat.v1.saved_model.build_tensor_info(input_secret)},
            outputs={"encoded_image": tf.compat.v1.saved_model.build_tensor_info(output_stegastamp),
                     "residual": tf.compat.v1.saved_model.build_tensor_info(output_residual)},
            method_name=tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
        )
    )
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        new_sess, [tf.compat.v1.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: predict_signature_def}
    )
    builder.save()
```

I followed the suggestions given by chatgpt. The general steps are:

1. Load the original model.
2. Obtain the input and output nodes and obtain the `subgraph` through
   `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph()`.
3. Create a new session and graph and import the `subgraph`.
4. Obtain the `subgraph` variable list, obtain the original model variables and assign values.
5. Save the `subgraph` model. However in step 4. I am completely unable to get the variable list, even if I use `tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)`, the result is still an empty set. How should I modify my program? thank you all！

Comment: When we separating model into two parts for encoding and decoding first we need to load the original  model and extract the subgraphs for encoding and decoding as before. And we need to get the list of all global variables in the original model using `tf.compat.v1.global_variables()`.
When we assigning values to the variables in the new graph, make sure need to use the correct names. We extract the name of the variable from the original graph and then use `tf.compat.v1.assign` to assign the value to the corresponding  variable in the new graph.